# How can i show data of a object attribute in html table?

Tags: sql, django, oracle

[image]I have a object attribute in a table with one attribute(quantity) which show the number of a product in a store. To show the data of that object in oracle a create a function in body which is getvalue() . The function works nice in oracle and everything, but i cant use that function when i need to display the data of that object in a website.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT  rednibroj, brojfakture, quantity, cena, pdv ,napomena FROM stavkafakture"
```

This is in django that im executing this query, the data of quantity comes like this:

```
<cx_Oracle.Object MASTER.QUANTITYat 0x41642e50>
```

Because quantity is the name of the object.

When i use the function quantity.getvalue() in that query it says that i cant.

Does anyone know how can i get the data of quantity in html table?

Comment: Where is your python models class code, paste it and it method and I can help you to do what you are expecting.

Comment: @Mbambadev im not using the model for this function, im just getting the data from oracle a print it in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Templates configuration is set correctly to show content of that object in template you must do simple:

{{myobject.attribut}} or {{myobject.method}}

But you must be sure the object exist in context if not you cannot show it in template.

Comment: Yes the method is perfect, its working on oracle 
where should i put this?
inside the query

Comment: No inside a template. That's what I have asking you before your code and you project structure

Comment: ill put in a link now, sorry

Comment: How do you want to use that link ? Give me example.

Comment: no i was saying the picture in the description for u to see the template.

Comment: If my answer is verified mark it  "answered " to help other persons

Comment: You are welcome, if you have other problems, post your question. Someone come to help you.